# Launch console application from WPF application in debug and release modes

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-console

Using a WPF application, all console output goes to the Visual Studio output window if you use debug mode or in release mode, no Console appears. Is it an anomaly? If you know a workaround? I want my console appears in two modes.. thank you in advance.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Program.Main();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `Debug.WriteLine` or `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: no difference between Debug.WriteLine and Console.WriteLine . Same behavior

Comment: Am I correct assuming that you are trying to get messages in output window in Release mode?

Comment: Yes, you are correct in assuming. but in any case  I have the same behavior, whether in release or debug mode.

Comment: Yes, it writes to output window even in Release Mode

Comment: Debug.WriteLine and Console.WriteLine are _not_ the same, the debug version is decorated with the `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` so calls to it will only be compiled if the project build properties have "Define DEBUG constant" enabled, which is typically only done for debug builds. The Console version, on the other hand, works the same in all builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change project "Output type" to "Console Application" and you will see both: app window and console.

[image]